# How to enlarge size for fraction using sympy and pythontex

Tags: python, sympy, pdflatex

I've just started used pythontex lately and I realise that fraction displayed from using `sympy` is smaller than the usual fraction. So I wonder if there is any way to enlarge the size of fraction in `sympy`. Below is a minimal working problem, of what I am working on and two images displaying what my code produces, and what I would like it to display.

## Current output

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnJ8R.png)

## Desired output

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pMOQ.png)

## Code

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{pythontex} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{pycode} 
from sympy import * 
x = symbols("x") 
f= 2*x-3 
sol = solve(f) 
\end{pycode} 
Equation $2x- 3 =0$ has one solution $x = \py{latex(sol[0])}$. 
\end{document}
```

**Update:** I've just realize the problem come from `latex` output for fraction is `\frac` in `python`. And to fix that, I have to put \displaystyle in every code which I use pythontex. So the new question is how to change the latex output for fraction in sympy from `\frac` to `\dfrac`